# Preventing 200 (Cached) responses

Tags: django, apache, caching

I just deployed a Django app with majority of the front-end code in Javascript files. The problem is, whenever I make an update to my JS files, that is not reflected on if someone opens the page, since they get a **'200 (Cached)' response**, and are getting the previous version of the Static file. A CTRL-F5 fixes this of course.

What would be the best way to deal with this issue? Where would a problem like this be solved?

- Headers in the Django response?
- Some Apache config (since the static files are server directly from
  Apache)
- Something else?

I don't want to go through the route of renaming files after each change, it doesn't seem like a clean solution for me. Any proper technique of achieving this?

One thing that I noticed, the `200 (cached)` response that I get has these among the headers:

```
Expires:Fri, 28 Nov 2014 04:11:29 GMT
Last-Modified:Sun, 28 Sep 2014 19:43:58 GMT
```

The Last modified infact should be around 29 Sep 2014 09:14 GMT. Could it be something to do with the `Expires` header? If yes, how should I set expires to, maybe, a day or less in the future? Again, this has to be done via Apache I presume?

NOTE: Performance gain/loss due to caching is absolutely not a concern here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/latest/django.html#add-gzip-and-caching-support) or [django-compressor](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to handle this.

Most production deployments of Django minify the CSS/JS at first fetch-time, and name the resultant file using a checksum. That way, the files can be cached forever, since if they're changed, a different filename will result.

Since there are apps available for this already, hopefully this won't cause you too much trouble.